# How can I get the details of a recyclerview item without the adapterPosition?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerView in my kotlin app that shows a list of items, when i click on one my app navigates to other fragment that shows the details of that recyclerview item, my problem is when I filter the results, it uses the adapterPosition that in this case, its different from the position of the data in the json.

When I filter the data with searchView, I submit to the adapter the new list with the filters applied.

Fragment where the recyclerview is:
(Here i would like to send as a string one of the fields shown in the recyclerview item i click)

```
private var museumsListAdapter=MuseumsListAdapter{ it ->
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putInt(INDICE,it)
        }
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_ListMuseumsFragment_to_detailsMuseumFragment, bundle)
    }
```

Adapter of the recyclerView:

```
class MuseumsListAdapter(private val onMuseumSelected: (Int) -> Unit):
    ListAdapter<MuseumsFieldsItem, MuseumsListViewHolder>(MuseumsFieldsItem.DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MuseumsListViewHolder {
        val itemView=MuseumListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MuseumsListViewHolder(itemView.root){
            onMuseumSelected(it)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MuseumsListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}
```

ViewHolder of the recyclerview:

```
lass MuseumsListViewHolder(itemView: View, private val onItemClicked: (Int) ->Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val itemBinding=MuseumListItemBinding.bind(itemView)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener{
            onItemClicked(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
```

And in the other fragment (details one) I get the value "INDICE" of the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MuseumsListAdapter(private val onMuseumSelected: (Int) -> Unit):
```

this is a callback which takes in an int, so just don't use int :)

```
class MuseumsListAdapter(private val onMuseumSelected: (Foo) -> Unit):
```

where Foo represents whatever you model is, make use of Museum in your case

inside your:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener{
        onMuseumSelected(adapterPosition)
}
```

you now need an instance of your Museum class.

by using `private val onMuseumSelected: (Foo) -> Unit` you'll get back a complete model to your fragment/activity, so you can use whatever field you need

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It didnt work for me, I don't know what to pass on the viewHolder and in the bundle of the fragment

Comment: do you have an arraylist of items inside MuseumsListAdapter ? how is it populated ?

Comment: Im my viewmodel I call an api rest service and then I get a LiveData that I observe in my fragment; in my adapter there is a list of my object "museum", when I dont filter the results it works fine with the position, but when I filter them and submit the new filtered list to the adapter, the problem comes when going to the details fragment